# Problem with creating two objects with one controller action with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, active-model-serializers

I am trying to send one post to a create in a controller and create two objects. For some reason the contoller only will create a company. I did a similair thing in sinatra and it worked. I know that the route is correct and so is the object the post sends.

Conrtoller:

```
 def index
    stocks = current_user.stocks
    render json: stocks, include: ['company']
  end
```

```
 def create
    company = Comapny.find_or_create_by(name: params["company"])
    stock = current_user.stocks.create(stock_params)
    render json: stock, status: :created
   end
```

Params:

```
def stock_params
    params.require(:stock).permit(:name, :price_purchased_at, :number, :info, :restaurant )
  end
```

Serializer:

```
class StockSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :price_purchased_at, :info, :number, :company

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I have tried changing the serializer and the params. I have also tried leaving out the company create line to see if it will create the stock but it still won't create a stock.

Comment: First, there is a typo in `Comapny`. Second, would you mind sharing the log entry for an example request to that route including received `params`, database queries and potential error messages? Third, you might want to replace the `current_user.stocks.create` with `current_user.stocks.create!` which will raise an error when the stock was not valid.

Comment: I apologize, I had caught that typo in Company earlier. These are the received params and the error after adding the bang: 

Parameters: {"name"=>"SuperStocks", "price_purchased_at"=>"500", "number"=>"500", "info"=>"Big Company", "company"=>"Microsoft", "stock"=>{"name"=>"SuperStocks", "price_purchased_at"=>"500", "number"=>"500", "info"=>"Big Company"}}

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Company must exist):
  
app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Like I said before, it does end up creating the company before sending this error for stocks.

Comment: User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in `current_user'
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Microsoft"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  Company Exists? (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Microsoft"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Comment: ↳ app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  Company Create (31.5ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Microsoft"], ["created_at", "2022-10-29 22:41:26.947086"], ["updated_at", "2022-10-29 22:41:26.947086"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (13.8ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:9:in `create'

Answer (score 1):

You ensure in your `create` that a company with the expected name exists. But you do not pass the found company to the stock creation method. Therefore, the stock creation fails with `Company must exist`.

Just change your `create` method to this:

```
def create
  company = Company.find_or_create_by(name: params['company'])
  stock = current_user.stocks.create!(stock_params.merge(company_id: company.id))

  render json: stock, status: :created
end
```